# How can a comma-separated return statement in Lua act as a function call?

Tags: lua, return

I'm new to Lua and trying to figure out how the **return** statement in the **squares** function below is being used in the following code snippet:

```
function squares(iteratorMaxCount)
   return square,iteratorMaxCount,0
end
```

The **square** parameter in the return statement refers to a function with the following signature:

```
function square(iteratorMaxCount,currentNumber)
```

What's confusing me is that the **return** statement *looks* like it's returning three values. What I *think* it's actually doing, however, is passing **iteratorMaxCount** and **0** as the arguments to a **square** function call.

Can anyone explain to me what's happening with this syntax? How is this serving as a function call as opposed to returning three values? In my mind, it feels as though the return statement *should* be written **return square(iteratorMaxCount, 0)** as opposed to **return square, iteratorMaxCount, 0**. I know that this is obviously wrong, but I can't figure out why.

I've tried searching through the Lua Manual, Lua Reference Guide, and searching Google, but I can't seem to find anything that explains this particular syntax. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Thanks in advance.

Full code below via 
[Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_iterators.htm)

```
function square(iteratorMaxCount,currentNumber)

   if currentNumber<iteratorMaxCount
   then
      currentNumber = currentNumber+1
      return currentNumber, currentNumber*currentNumber
   end

end

function squares(iteratorMaxCount)
   return square,iteratorMaxCount,0
end  

for i,n in squares(3)
do 
   print(i,n)
end
```

Comment: I'll take a look in my Lua book when I get home, but I think this has to do with the "generic for loop" syntax. It's not very clear code anyways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`squares` really does return three values, the first of which is a function. `squares` does not call `square` at all.

The trick here is how the `for` ... `in` syntax works. In the Lua 5.3 Reference Manual, section 3.3.5 says:

> A **for** statement like:
>
> ```
> for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do block end
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the code:
>
> ```
>  do
>    local f, s, var = explist
>    while true do
>      local var_1, ···, var_n = f(s, var)
>      if var_1 == nil then break end
>      var = var_1
>      block
>    end
>  end
> ```

So the keyword "`in`" needs to be followed by three values:

1. an "iterator function" for getting the variables in each iteration
2. a "state" value to pass to the function each time
3. an initial value to pass to the function the first time

After the first time the function is called, the first value from the previous call is passed back into the next function call. When the first value returned from the function is `nil`, the `for` loop ends.

So in this example, `squares(max)` is designed to be used after "`in`", using `square` as the iterator function, `max` as the "state", `0` as the initial value, and a number and its square as the loop data values.